# New style to show the hint to the user in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-popupwindow

How to show such kind of hints or instructions for the user, and after tap on this the hints it will be invisible.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

Comment: I just go with this project.It will show the tool tips text but cannot show the circle like structure representing zooming to the text as shown in above image.

Answer (score 1):

Go for the `SuperToolTips` which is open source and creates a Custom tooltips for the views as per your needs.

You can check out its sample and library [HERE](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)

Comment: I just go with this project.It will show the tool tips text but cannot show the circle like structure representing zooming to the text as shown in above image.